# How can i create gift card in magento community edition

Tags: magento-1.7

I am trying to create custom magento module extension for gift card. Does anyone know how can i create gift card extension for magento community edition. how to create code pool? to generate gift code? thanks in advance.

Comment: Questins about Magento should be asked on http://magento.stackexchange.com